# awk, sed, shell Help: How to use data from one file to another - Take 2

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have two files with the following format:

f1.txt

```
1
banana 3
apple 1.0
ref 15
```

f2.txt

```
2
banana 9999
apple unknown
ref unknown9
```

How can I have the value for 'apple' and 'banana' from f1.txt be used in place of the what's written for f2.txt? I would like f2.txt to be updated to read:

```
2
banana 3
apple 1.0
ref unknown9
```

I tried using the following:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}($1 in a){$2=a[$1]}1'  f1 f2 > fnew
```

However, this gives

```
2
banana 3
apple 1.0
ref 15
```

Notice 'ref' is the issue. All I want changed is 'apple' and 'banana' but the above command changed 'ref' too.  FYI, the files (f1.txt and f2.txt) can be ordered differently. Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: why is the second banana?  And why it is set to 2?

Comment: How do we know which fields should be updated? Only fruit? Do yo have a third file with fields that can be updated?

Comment: Also, is 9999 same as unknown?

Comment: updating now.... slight error

Comment: You need ref not to be updated by file1?

Comment: In this instance yes.... 9999 could be another unkown

Comment: correct.... I'm not looking at updating 'ref'

Comment: Are the both files ordered the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk -v na='unknown|9999' 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} 
                 $1 in a && na~$2 {$2=a[$1]}1' file1 file2

banana 3
apple 1.0
ref unknown9
```

if you want to replace only apple an banana, regardless of values

```
awk -v keys='apple banana' '
                BEGIN   {kn=split(keys,ks); 
                         for(i=1;i<=kn;i++) k[ks[i]]}
                NR==FNR {if($1 in k) a[$1]=$2; next} 
                $1 in a {$2=a[$1]}1' file1 file2
```

**Explanation**

> `keys='apple banana'` create a key list to restrict the changes to keys only,
>
> `kn=split(keys,ks)...` create the array lookup for keys in the BEGIN block
>
> `NR==FNR {if($1 in k) a[$1]=$2..` while processing the first file compile the lookup table for key value pairs for only specified keys
>
> `$1 in a {$2=a[$1]}` now in the second file, check the key/value pair exists if so replace the value from the lookup table
>
> `1` print

Comment: This works! For my robustness, Is there anyway rather than use 'unknown|9999' we reference the awk command to banana and apple?

Comment: Is the goal to replace all N/A values or only apple and banana?

Comment: The goal is to replace the values only. These values can keep changing, that's why it would be best not to reference the values.

Comment: do you mean keys or values?  How do you know which ones to replace?  Based on keys or values?  Note the convention is the lines can be regarded as "key value" pairs.

Comment: I know what the keys are in the file and each key (apple, banana etc.) is unique.  The second approach works very well for me! Can you explain to me what each part of you awk command is doing? I'm new to awk and I'm trying to learn along the way. Thanks again for taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}($1 in a) && ($1 != "ref"){$2=a[$1]}1'  f1 f2 > fnew
```

Alternative:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}($1 in a) && ($2 != "unknown9"){$2=a[$1]}1'  f1 f2 > fnew
```

Comment: I may have over simplified the problem... the files I'm working with can have many line and the order is random. What if there are more instance (many more) where I don't want variables changed?

Comment: @user7649922 Look at the alternative. Will not update any line in which field 2 is "unknown9". Can be extended to more values. You need somehow to distinguish the lines / fields that not to be updated ....

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr '/^ref/!s/^(.*) (.*)/s#^\1.*#\1 \2#/p' file1 | sed -f - file2
```

Create a sed script from the first file and run it against the second.